# php loop and skip over if file exists

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

I need some help with some PHP logic.  I'm adding images to my directory where some images already exist.  I'm trying to loop over the directory and skip over the names if they exist...hard to explain...here's what I have:

```
if(isset($_POST['imgName'])){
$artName = $_POST['imgName'];
if ($_FILES['file']['name'][0] != ""){
    $num = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++){
        $fileExt = str_replace("image/", ".", $_FILES['file']['type'][$i]);
        $newFileName = "..//images/$num$artName$fileExt";
        if (file_exists($newFileName)){
            $num++;
            $newFileName = "..//images/".$num.$artName.$fileExt;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $newFileName);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I tried doing a while loop and a do while loop and I couldn't get it to work...maybe I was doing it wrong.  Can I please get some advice?  Thanks...

This is for a blog so the $artName is the article name...the $num [0] will be the main image and the rest will be the gallery images

Comment: Have you ever thought of obfuscating the file names? IE, take the base file name, append the current time stamp onto the string, the use `md5()` to create a new filename? This way would be extremely unlikely to ever overwrite files.

Comment: May or may not be an issue, however those 2x `/` in both your `..//images/` one of them should be taken away. I.e.: `../images/`

Comment: @JustinWood I know that way of doing it but I'm doing this for a blog and I'm trying to use the blog entry name for the images so it will be simple to output it...i.e images/0articlename.jpeg will be the main article image, images/1-...articlename.jpeg will be for the gallery

Comment: @Fred-ii- The slashes aren't an issue, I check before.  I just can't seem to get the logic to work with what I have...

Answer (score 0):

WORKAROUND SOLUTION:

```
if(isset($_POST['imgName'])){
$artName = $_POST['imgName'];
if ($_FILES['file']['name'][0] != ""){
    $pics = glob('..//images/*'.$artName.'*');
    if($pics[0] != ""){
        for($j=0; $j<count($pics); $j++){
            $path = pathinfo($pics[$j]);
            $ext = $path['extension'];
            rename($pics[$j], "..//images/".$j.$artName.".".$ext);
        }
    }
    $num = count($pics);
    for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++){
        $fileExt = str_replace("image/", ".", $_FILES['file']['type'][$i]);
        $newFileName = "..//images/$num$artName$fileExt";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $newFileName);
        $num++;
    }
}
}
```

The workaround I came up with is checking the images related to the article which are already in the directory and renaming them.  Then using the count(of images in the directory) and setting that to the $num and using the $num as part of the new image name...this way there are no duplicates.  It there's a better solution, I'd love to hear it...